# How to start multiple separate functions with the same button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on an interactive fiction project that allows the user to choose multiple pathways through the story. I have a div with the narrative (#bigtext) and a box with three options in it (#Option1, #Option2, #Option3 - all designated with HTML span elements) and clicking an option activates a function which updates both the text and the options for the next "page" of the story. Each "page" is a different function which means I can have full control over the background, so refreshing the page is out of the question.

When I click on an option, it activates the function. All text fades out, is updated via javascript and then fades back in again. My problem is that when I click the button again, it not only calls the desired function, but also the one designated for the previous button. I've attached a sample of the code to demonstrate.

**This is the function that updates the story.**

```
    function Prologue(){
//Narrative Goes Here
    document.getElementById("bigtext").innerHTML = "STORY HERE";        
//Options/Inputs go Here
    document.getElementById("Option1").innerHTML = "CONTINUE";  
    document.getElementById("Option2").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("Option3").innerHTML = "";  

//Entrance animations go here
$("#bigtext").delay(1500).fadeToggle(1000); 
$("#optionsbox").delay(2000).fadeToggle(1000);  

//On Option Clicked

//Option 1
$('#Option1').mouseup(function() { 
$("#bigtext").fadeToggle(1000); 
$("#optionsbox").fadeToggle(1000);  
     setTimeout(Prologue2, 1500);
    });

        }
```

I repeat this for each "page" of the story, so Prologue2 is the next function or "page".

**Here is my HTML, which I would like to keep as it's quite streamlined (to my eyes anyway)**

```
<div id="bigtext"> </div>
<div id="optionsbox"> 
<span id="Option1"></span> <br/>
<span id="Option2"></span> <br/>
<span id="Option3"></span> <br/>
</div>
```

I've found that by the time I get to "Prologue2", it's calling not only "Prologue3" when I click on the option, but also "Prologue2" again as I have previously used the same button to designate that function. Is there a better way in which I could go about this or somehow remove the previous function after it has been used?

Comment: Can you place the code where it calls `Prologue3`?

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would not keep the same `#OptionX` elements all the way, because you never know, you might want to have different numbers of options for some "scenes". Instead, you can dynamically create those options.

Also, good luck with your project. I've thought of that in the past, but it's a lot of work, to write every scene, and you need to think ahead about what you might need (environment variables, for example, ie: did the user previously do something?)

Here is how I would do it (sorry for the bad story):

```js
    // Variables you can use in your story
var env,
    // Page list
    pages = [
    // 0
    {
        bigtext: function(){
            return "Two doors are presented to you"
                 + (env.doorOpened ? " (again)" : "")
                 + ". Which one would you like to open?";
        },
        callback: function(){
            env.doorOpened = true;
        },
        options: [
            {text: "Door A", callback: function(){ goToPage(1); }},
            {text: "Door B", callback: function(){ goToPage(2); }}
        ]
    },
    // 1
    {
        bigtext: function(){
            return "Damn it, there's a tiger in there!"
                 + (env.metTheCat ? " The cat was more friendly!" : "");
        },
        options: [
            {text: "Close the door", callback: function(){ goToPage(0); }},
            {text: "Go in anyway", callback: function(){ goToPage(3); }}
        ]
    },
    // 2
    {
        bigtext: function(){
            return "That's odd, there's a cat playing the guitar in there...";
        },
        callback: function(){
            env.metTheCat = true;
        },
        options: [
            {text: "Listen to him", callback: function(){ goToPage(4); }},
            {text: "Go back", callback: function(){ goToPage(0); }}
        ]
    },
    // 3
    {
        bigtext: function(){
            return "You just died. What were you thinking?!";
        },
        options: [
            {text: "Restart", callback: function(){ resetGame(); }}
        ]
    },
    // 4
    {
        bigtext: function(){
            return "That was some good music. Who would have thought a cat could play this well?";
        },
        options: [
            {text: "Go back", callback: function(){ goToPage(0); }}
        ]
    }
];

// Start a game on page load
$(resetGame);


/*
 * Reset variables and display first page
 */
function resetGame(){
    env = {
        currentPage: 0,
        elements : {
            wrapper: $('#wrapper'),
            bigText: $('#bigtext'),
            optionsContainer: $('#optionsbox')            
        },
        userCanClick: false
    };
    showCurrentPage();
}

/*
 * Display current page
 */
function showCurrentPage(){
    var page = pages[env.currentPage];
    env.elements.bigText.html(page.bigtext());
    env.elements.optionsContainer.html('');
    page.options.forEach(function(opt){
        var $opt = $('<div class="option">'+opt.text+'</div>');
        $opt.click(function(){
            env.userCanClick = false;
            opt.callback();
        });
        env.elements.optionsContainer.append($opt);
    });
    if(page.callback){
        page.callback();
    }
    env.elements.wrapper.fadeIn(200, function(){
        env.userCanClick = true;
    });
}

/*
 * Go to page number X
 */
function goToPage(x){
    env.elements.wrapper.fadeOut(200, function(){
        env.currentPage = x;
        showCurrentPage();
    });
}
```

```css
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 2rem;
}
#bigtext{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    margin: 1em;
}
.option{
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    margin: .3rem auto;
    background: #f13c14;
    color: #fff;
    max-width: 20rem;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.option:hover{
    background: #de2e08;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="bigtext"></div>
    <div id="optionsbox"></div>.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's above and beyond what I expected! It's been a project I've had in the back of my head for a while and I've finally got time to do it! I'll give you a credit!

Comment: @MattBradley Always happy to help! This is a basic system for you to navigate between pages while keeping tabs of some variables, but if you want other features, you should be able to build them into it. Again, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just need to clear any previously set onMouseUp events before setting the new one.

```
$('#Option1').off("mouseup");
```